# OOM error even after clearing GPU Session

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, conv-neural-network, cross-validation

I am applying CNN on a data set with 4684 images of size 2000*102. I am using 5 fold cross validation in keras for recording performance metrics. I am using `del.model()`, `del.histroy` and `K.clear_session()` but after 2 running two folds its giving OOM error. Please see the developed algorithm below. running on 1080Ti with 11GB memory. PC memory 32GB

```
kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True)
kf.get_n_splits(data_new)

AUC_SCORES = []
KAPPA_SCORES = []
MSE = []
Accuracy = []
for train, test in kf.split(data_new):
    Conf_model = None
    Conf_model = Sequential()
    Conf_model.add(Conv2D(32, (20,102),activation='relu',input_shape=(img_rows,img_cols,1),padding='same',data_format='channels_last'))
    Conf_model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),padding='same',dim_ordering="th"))
    Conf_model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    Conf_model.add(Flatten())     
    Conf_model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))  
    Conf_model.add(Dropout(0.5))        
    Conf_model.add(Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))
    Conf_model.compile(loss=keras.losses.binary_crossentropy, optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(),metrics=['accuracy'])

    data_train = data_new[train]
    data_train.shape
    labels_train = labels[train]

    data_test = data_new[test]
    data_test_Len = len(data_test)
    data_train = data_train.reshape(data_train.shape[0],img_rows,img_cols,1)
    data_test = data_test.reshape(data_test.shape[0],img_rows,img_cols,1)
    data_train = data_train.astype('float32')
    data_test = data_test.astype('float32')
    labels_test = labels[test]
    test_lab = list(labels_test)#test_lab.append(labels_test)
    labels_train = to_categorical(labels_train,num_classes)
    labels_test_Shot = to_categorical(labels_test,num_classes)
    print("Running Fold")
    history = Conf_model.fit(data_train, labels_train, batch_size=batch_size,epochs=epochs,verbose=1)
    Conf_predicted_classes=Conf_model.predict(data_test)
    Conf_predict=Conf_model.predict_classes(data_test)
    Conf_Accuracy = accuracy_score(labels_test, Conf_predict)
    Conf_Mean_Square = mean_squared_error(labels_test, Conf_predict)
    Label_predict = list(Conf_predict)#Label_predict.append(Conf_predict)
    Conf_predicted_classes = np.argmax(np.round(Conf_predicted_classes),axis=1)
    Conf_Confusion = confusion_matrix(labels_test, Conf_predicted_classes)
    print(Conf_Confusion)
    Conf_AUC = roc_auc_score(labels_test, Conf_predict)
    print("AUC value for Conf Original Data: ", Conf_AUC)
    Conf_KAPPA = cohen_kappa_score(labels_test, Conf_predict)
    print("Kappa value for Conf Original Data: ", Conf_KAPPA)
    AUC_SCORES.append(Conf_AUC)
    KAPPA_SCORES.append(abs(Conf_KAPPA))
    MSE.append(Conf_Mean_Square)
    Accuracy.append(Conf_Accuracy)
    del history
    del Conf_model
    K.clear_session()
```

Error below

```
ResourceExhaustedError: OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1632000,64] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc
     [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/dense_1/MatMul_grad/MatMul_1}} = MatMul[T=DT_FLOAT, transpose_a=true, transpose_b=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](flatten_1/Reshape, training/Adam/gradients/dense_1/Relu_grad/ReluGrad)]]
Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

I tried the below code and seems like it worked.

```
  def clear_mem():
     try: tf.sess.close()
     except: pass
     sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
     K.set_session(sess)
     return
```

Comment: Dumb question but can you take a look at `nvidia-smi` and monitor it throughout? Particularly when the first model is killed, do a `time.sleep()` to see if the memory is freed before the second model is created. If I'm not wrong (probably am) memory won't be freed. I'm assuming you're using `tf-keras` or the `tensorflow` backend?

Comment: Thanks for the response, I am running on windows so I used GPU-Z to monitor memory. Any suggestion on how to clear GPU memory after each fold. I am using Tensorflow backend. But the issue is it used to work before with the same code. Now it started throwing errors.

Comment: Running GPU-Z was my hypothesis correct in that it's not being freed between instantiations?

Comment: could you run `tf.get_default_graph().finalize()` just before running the first train step? Does it raise any error? Or does it still finish to train for the given epochs?

Comment: gabirele, I added your suggestion before the model.fit and it threw below error.  raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")

RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.

Comment: @IanQuah I observed as you said and it's not clearing memory. Is there a way to do this after the every fold. At the start it takes 9.5GB and  I am not sure how its able to run two folds and then for the third fold its throwing an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few suggestions considering the updates in the comments:

1) Create a bash script that launches the python scripts individually (after the process dies, the memory is freed) and have them write results to separate files that you can later process and join together. E.g use a bash script that iterates and feeds 1) a seed, and 2) the current index to the python script. Using the seed, you ensure that there is no leakage in fold splits, and using the index you can just grab the relevant portion

2) Use a python process to multiprocess the results

Having worked with tensorflow in python multiprocessing before my recommendation is method 1). There were many gotchas that I faced while implementing this

Do these methods make sense?

Comment: Hi, I used the code which I edited in question. That resolved the error. I defined that function outside cross-validation and called it in cross-validation. Now I am not encountering any error. Can you say if there is any thing wrong in this.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure, sorry :/ I don't really use keras and the tensorflow version I use is a little old so I'm not sure if the knowledge I have really carries over. I don't really understand how the method you're using functions though, because from [tf github issues list](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19731) it seems like there's no in-built way to free memory. Having said that if it works it works. I would say do verify that the model is training correctly (before training error high, predictions v bad but after training error low and predictions better)

Comment: Sure Thanks. I found this in fast.ai https://forums.fast.ai/t/gpu-garbage-collection/1976/2

Comment: [Keras Github Issue: clear_session() doesn't clear memory from GPU](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/9379) might be worth looking into. Sorry I can't help more - I wasn't even aware that this was a thing now. But if it doesn't work out, keep the method I mentioned in mind and it'll probably work (worked for my company)

Comment: This is great. Thanks

Comment: @VMan Sorry, but where to put that clear_mem function exactly? Should I call it somewhere then? Could you elaborate on that more?